# Excel Vba sumif function array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sumifs

I am wanting to transfer a worksheet formula i have in a spreadsheet,but cannot seem to find how to do it, I could write multiple sumifs but i need to do it for approx 11 types, so not the cleanest way. The issue comes down to the columns being summed and consecutive but obviously depending on the month could be just N or N,O or N,O,P,Q etc
This is entered using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

My formula in Excel is

```
Sum(if(Range=Criteria,if(range=<criteria,Range)))

=Sum(if(Data!$A$4:$A$1000=$A11,if(Data!$N$3:$Y$3<=EOMONTH($A$1,-2)+1,Data$N$4:$Y$1000)))
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above formula can be also written as

`=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$4:$A$1000=11)*(Data!$N$3:$Y$3<=EOMONTH($A$1,-2)+1)*(Data!$N$4:$Y$1000))`

And this is not an array formula. i.e you do not have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. A simple <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will suffice.

The same can be ported to VBA as

`Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$4:$A$1000=11)*(Data!$N$3:$Y$3<=EOMONTH($A$1,-2)+1)*(Data!$N$4:$Y$1000))")`

Comment: Legend, cant believe that i didn't think of sumproduct!